# antlr "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError" on grammar action

Tags: java, parsing, exception, antlr4

I was trying to use rule reference in grammar action.

```
string_decl_list  : (string_decl)+;
string_decl       : ('STRING' id ':=' str ';') 
{//table.currentScope().define(new BaseDescriptor(), id.text, ValueType.STRING);
 System.out.println($str.text);
};
str               : STRINGLITERAL;
```

My grammar looks like this. The compilation is fine. But when I try to parse my file.

There's an exception coming out.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: str
at MicroParser.string_decl(MicroParser.java:368)
at MicroParser.string_decl_list(MicroParser.java:312)
at MicroParser.decl(MicroParser.java:246)
at MicroParser.pgm_body(MicroParser.java:187)
at MicroParser.program(MicroParser.java:107)
at Compiler.main(Compiler.java:32)
Java Result: 1
```

I guess I am doing it right for the rule reference, could anyone help me about this? I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You get the error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: str
```

because you don't have a return value for the parser rule "str".

Try something like this:

```
 str returns [String str] :  STRINGLITERAL { $str = new String($STRINGLITERAL.text); } ;
```

Comment: Are you saying that put this in grammar file? Sorry for the late reply.